# show heatmap on Codeigniter googlemap v3 library

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I've been using codeigniter google map v3 library by bio stall, currently i want to create some heatmap, it is already provided by googlemaps. documentation already cover on this URL

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer#customize_a_heatmap_layer
```

but currently i little bit confuse how to use that heatmap on the Codeigniter library, which part that I've to modified to create a heatmap for Codeigniter google map v3 library ?

Comment: What you mean by this **Which part that I've to modified to create a heatmap for Codeigniter**

Comment: @Abdulla please see my question above "I've been using codeigniter google map v3 library by bio stall"

Answer (score 1):

I found here a tutorial on how to use [CodeIgniter in Google Maps API Library](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library/).

The library enables you to create a map and overlay multiple markers, polylines, polygons, rectangles, ground overlays and/or circles, all of which are fully customizable. The library also supports showing directions between two points, including the ability to show the textual directions alongside the map too, and marker clustering. The first stages of integration with the Google Places API are available for use too.

For more information and some explanation, you can visit this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldo6eP-EBZ8) on how to use CodeIgniter in Google Maps API.

Comment: Hi @KENdi i already use that library, i just want additional features, a heatmap, please see again my questions

Answer (score 1):

According to the script in the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap), the only part related to backend is to provide the points.

```
function getPoints() {
  return [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783206, -122.440829),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783273, -122.440324),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783316, -122.440023),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783371, -122.439687),
    ...
```

So you can either echo it in php like

```
    <?php
    //...
    echo  "new google.maps.LatLng($lat, $lng),\n"
    //...
```

where $lat and $lng must be set in php as iterated through points, or return AJAX response in getPoints method.

Comment: hi @Emrah Izci, thank for comment, my problem is how integrate that documentation with biostall library for google map, i'm using biostall library for codeigniter